# react-router-dom how to navigate back (not in history)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have some nested routes, and I need to navigate back "a level up" so to say.

I'm using `react-router-dom v5.3.1`

`history.goBack()` will take me to last visited page, as if I use the back button in the browser. I don't need this.

Imagine my history looks something like this...:

```
[
  dashboard/1/sub-page/7
  dashboard/1/sub-page/13
  dashboard/1/sub-page/9
  dashboard/1/sub-page/1
]
```

My browser URL is: `localhost:8080&app.html#/dashboard/1/sub-page/7`

Does `react-router-dom` provide a safe way for navigating to: `localhost:8080&app.html#/dashboard/1` - or what would be a decent approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `history` object can only navigate to specifically defined paths via a path string with `.push`/`.replace`, or navigate forward/backward via a delta with `.go`.

You can create a "goToParent" handler that reads the current matched location's `pathname` and slice off the last path segment and issue a PUSH.

Example:

```
import { useLocation, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

...

const { pathname } = useLocation();
const history = useHistory();

const goUpLevel = () => {
  const parent = pathname.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/");
  history.push(parent);
}
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-how-to-navigate-back-not-in-history]

If you wanted to go two levels up, i.e. from `"/dashboard/1/sub-page/7"` to `"/dashboard/1"` then use `.slice(0, -2)` to slice off the last ***two*** segments.

Comment: I don't have access to `useLocation` and `useHistory` as they are not part of major v5. But the idea of splitting the path, removing the 2 last parts and reconstruction it again works nicely. Thanks for the inspiration

Comment: @RasmusPuls They most certainly are hooks in `react-router-dom@5`. See [v5 useHistory](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) and `[v5 useLocation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation). Are you using React function components? If you are using class-based components I can tailor my answer for your use case.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware. I'm used to wrap my component with `withRouter()`, and then get `history` and `location` from props.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "." or ".." in your Link component to go one or two levels up.

```
<Link to=".">Go one level up</Link>
<Link to="..">Go two levels up</Link>
```

Another approach is to map routes into helpers so you can reutilize them all along the codebase:

```
// Routes helpers
const dashboardRoute = (id) => `/dashboard/${id}`;
const subPageRoute = (id, subId) => `/dashboard/${id}/sub-page/${subId}`; 

// Routes mapping
<Switch>
  <Route path={dashboardRoute(":id")}>
    <Dashboard />
  </Route>
  <Route path={subPageRoute(":id", ":subId")}>
    <SubPage/>
  </Route>
</Switch>

// Route helper usage
<Link to={dashboardRoute(id)} >Go to dashboard route</Link>
```

Comment: This, is interesting. Will try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `useNavigate()` hook from `react-router-dom`.

As I can see [this](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate) might satisfy your need by passing a delta as an argument to the navigate function, or you can simply pass the route you want to go.

Comment: The OP is using v5.3.1, useNavigate is introduced in v6

Comment: Totally missed that. thanks.